# Applying the central limit while having the sample standard deviation

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

I have the following exercise:

> In a research report, Richard H. Weindruch of the UCLA Medical School
> claims that mice with an average life span of $32$ months will live to
> be about $40$ months old when $40$% of the calories in their diet are
> replaced by vitamins and protein. Is there any reason to believe that
> $μ < 40$ if $64$ mice that are placed on this diet have an average life of
> $38$ months with a standard deviation of $5.8$ months? Use a P-value in
> your conclusion.

From my personal understanding, in applying the central limit theorem we dividethe difference of the means by the sample standard deviation which is given as $5.8$, however in the solution they did the following:

$z=\frac{38-40}{\frac{5.8}{\sqrt{64}}}$, what I don't understand is that why we divided $5.8$ by $\sqrt{64}$, shouldn't we do that iff this value was the standard deviation for the population which isn't the case here.

Comment: The denominator is the standard deviation of the mean of the sample. If $X_i$ has a standard deviation $\sigma$ then the sample mean $\overline X=\frac1n\cdot \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$ has a standard deviation $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ Just calculate $Var\left(\frac1n\cdot \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i \right)$

Comment: It would be more usual to divide by the estimate of the *standard error of the mean*, which is the sample standard deviation divided by the square root of the sample size

Comment: @callculus and what if we are given the standard deviation of the population?

Comment: I am assuming if we have the standard deviation of the population we still use it as it would be a good estimate of the standard deviation of the population for a large sample size?

Comment: @Sergio I think you doubt is reasonable. If 5.8 is the standard deviation of the sample we have to multiply $\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}}$ to obtain an unbiased estimator for the population standard deviation. We will see if Henry has another opinion.

Comment: Thank you for your help!, what I meant is that if $5.8$ was the standard deviation of the population, how to proceed with the central limit theorem? I used to think that we divide the standard deviation of the population by $\sqrt{n}$ until I got to this question and the same was done with the standard deviation of the sample which got me posting this question

Comment: @Henry why is that? according to the definition of the central limit theorem "If ${X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n}}$ are random samples each of size $n$ taken from a population with overall mean $\mu$ and finite variance $\sigma ^{2}$ and if $\bar{X}$ is the sample mean, the limiting form of the distribution of $Z=\frac{\bar X - \mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}$as $n→∞$, is the standard normal distribution."

Comment: this implies that the standard deviation used is the one of the variance

Comment: Let´s say the standard deviation of the sample  is $s_{\overline x}$ then the standard deviation of the sample mean is $\frac{s_{\overline x}}{\sqrt n}$. And therefore the unbiased estimator of the standard deviation of the mean of the population is  $\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}}\cdot \frac{s_{\overline x}}{\sqrt n}$ In your case $s_x=5.8$ and $n=36$. So in your case the unbiased estimator of the standard deviation of the mean of the population is $\frac{5.8}{\sqrt{63}}$

Comment: @Sergio  You have said $Z=\frac{\bar X - \mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}$.  You can either say $\sigma$ is the population standard deviation or that $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ is the standard error of the mean.  They can be estimated from the sample with $s$ or $\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$.  It all amounts to the same thing

Comment: (+1) for Question based on OP's engagement in discussion.

Comment: thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many comments, some confusion, maybe no resolution:

Seems to me this is a left-sided, 1-sample t test of
$H_0: \mu=40$ against $H_1: \mu < 40$ based on sample mean and standard deviation
$\bar X =38, S = 5.8,$ respectively, for $n=64$ random observations
from a normal sample. Output from a recent release
of Minitab, which accepts summarized data:

```
One-Sample T 

Test of μ = 40 vs < 40


 N    Mean  StDev  SE Mean  95% Upper Bound      T      P
64  38.000  5.800    0.725           39.210  -2.76  0.004
```

I will leave it to you to show how to obtain the $T$ statistic (following @Henry's Comments)
and to show that you reject $H_0$ at the 5% level (or even the 1% level).

It is easy to see that $\bar X = 38 < 40.$
You have evidence that it is *significantly* less than 40, in a statistical sense.

*Note:* DF$=64-1=63$ for the $T$-statistic. P-value from R statistical software, where `pt` is the CDF of a t-distribution:

```
pt(-2.76, 63)
[1] 0.003780076
```

Comment: thank you for your answer!